# If I install Ubuntu 12.04, will it recognize all of my RAM?

Tags: ram

I have a question that's been bugging me since a long time. A friend of mine told me that when he had Ubuntu 11.10 installed the OS only recognized 3.4GB instead of 8GB. In the next week I'll be buying a new computer and I'll have 8GB  of RAM, does the Video Card need to have it's own video memory for the OS to recognize the RAM entirely?.

If you could give me some advise on how to configure my PC before I buy it it would be great.

Thanks.

---

Tengo una duda que me ronda de hace tiempo. Un amigo mio me comento que con ubuntu 11.10 tenia 8 gb de RAM y que solo le reconocia 3.4. Dentro de unos 5 dias me comprare un ordenador nuevo a base de componentes y voy a meterle 8 gb de RAM. ¿Hace falta que la tarjeta gráfica tenga Gb dedicados para que el sistema me reconozca la RAM entera?

Si podeis darme algunos consejillos sobre como configurar el PC antes de comprarmelo para que ese problema no me pase,

Muchisimas Gracias.

Comment: Please use English, most of the people here do not speak Spanish.

Comment: English is only language supported in this website. Please read [FAQ]. You can use google translator to post your question in english.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend was probably not using the 64bit version of Ubuntu, nor he was using the 32bit PAE kernel which does recognize the RAM.

Integrated GPUs take their video memory from the systems RAM memory, so I'd say yes get a discrete GPU instead if you want your RAM to be "fully" accessible to you.

Comment: ok thank you very much for the reply and I'm sorry I put the text in English.

Comment: If you feel that your question is solved, please click the tick under the voting tools. Cheers